# Change UI automatically according to the cell phone

Tags: android, user-interface, phone-call

I am designing a prank app for android in which i want to show as if someone has called and then when the user answers the call it should play the recorded file. I have finished most of the things apart from 1 issue which i am facing currently.

1) As we all know the UI of every phone is somewhat different when they get a call, so i want to make sure that when running the app it should use the phone's default UI, so as to make sure it looks like a real incoming call.

I am uploading a picture so you'll have a better idea regarding my query. So as we can see that the UI is different for every phone, how can i make sure that when my app makes a fake call it uses the same UI which is displayed while getting a real incoming call.

Any help on the problem would be highly appreciated.
[image]

Comment: I think you may be looking at this wrong. Your question isn't really handset related; what if the user changes the default app that is used for handling phone calls? or if they use a custom rom?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a way for you to know the customization done by the manufacturers.

Comment: @HaemEternal, what i what to do is the the app should trigger the default mechanism active at the time of using the app, currently it shows android 2.3.3 UI on whichever phone i've tried the app.

Comment: @Gogu what you'd advice me to do then?

Comment: Allow the user to select the theme they prefer!!

Comment: @TapanDesai if you are actually trying to start the default app that handles the call, that is reasonably straightforward are can be done using an intent. If you are trying to emulate in your app's UI, what the default app looks like, that sounds really hard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is start the Android Dialler app, and then to change the functionality/have it do nothing while you play an audio file.

While you could enable the loudspeaker and play audio, you can't make the dialler stay active without a live call. An invalid number would fail, and an actual call would cost money.

What you want to do is actually very hard to achieve and the only thing you could try to do is to create your own fake dialler activities with different themes (according to major brands), detect the device manufacturer and then display a relevant one.